# Facebook Subscriptions

Tags: facebook, facebook-subscriptions

On Facebook, if you change your subscription settings on one of your friends profiles, say you want to see less of their status updates and comments or more of them, will they be able to see that you made a change to your subscription to their profile?

Answer (score 5):

No, they can't. It's like any other setting in your account - it's private to you. However, they might notice that you respond to their posts less often.